# PHP IMAP get body text without reply

Tags: php, imap, email-parsing

I only want to get body text, without any **reply** text/html. When I use `imap_fetchbody` it gives all the text including primary email and replies text/html. Is there any way that I can get only mail text? Also, I have no exact text pattern for splitting or parsing the content from the end (red horizontal line). How can I achieve this?

[image]

I have tried `imap_fetchbody`, `imap_fetchstructure` to get only the primary email text, it gives all the text including reply email text. I can split text from **FROM:** but as you can see Random Name and other stuff will still appear which I need to remove.

Comment: Is there any standard way of designating parts of the message as the "original" message vs. embedded replies, signatures etc.? Without that, how would the API "know" which is which?

Comment: Not really sure, I tried to get email by parts but the plain text part resulted in the text given in the image. other parts were images or HTML embedded which is not my concern yet.

Comment: Emails doesn't really have any concept of "replies" or "history". The clients simply append the previous message body to the new message body (and indent/mark the previous message in their own way) and usually prefix the subject with `RE:` or similar. If you want to parse that out, you need to parse it out from the body yourself. How to do that depends on the format.

Comment: Every email client does it differently.  It is not part of the message structure, it's just "pasted" into the body with everything else.  You can only separate out the reply heuristically.